# clean out my keychain?

Tags: iphone, key

I am an iPhone programmer.  My developer cert just expired.  My keychain has a bunch of public/private key pairs floating around in it.  Would it be safe to clean them all out before requesting a new cert?  Or could that screw something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean them up..

As if in case you have deleted the one which you need to use in future then you can go on the website and can redownload it.

So dont think there can be any issue....

Comment: In my case, this proved to be true.  Though I don't know what other uses keys might have.  So for others, this might be dangerous.  One option would be to export all the keys before cleaning them out.

Comment: Absolutely true(the idea of export).... but if they are system keys. They will be regenerated again automatically. So no issues n nothin to worry.. :)